# Highhcarts with huge datasets in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I have **JSON data** of around 50 mb that i need to sent to Angularjs front end which will be used by highcharts to show line graphs. But the fetching such amount of data over **http** is really time consuming (timeouts too in some cases) impacting user experience. 
I also suggested , to client, to show aggregated data that reduces the sizes of json but client is not ready for that as that won't be of much use for analysis for his customers. Here is the [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gqp2r2n4/11/) with aggregated data. Just replace the query param  **file=1min_raw** in following piece of code with **file=merged_json** to check the time taken to download data and render chart.

```
$.getJSON('http://srijan-best.s114.srijan-sites.com/merged_script.php?file=1min_raw'
```

So is there a way in highcharts to show the data as soon as it starts receiving. ? I have gone through the docs but not able to find anything to me requirements.

Is there any other alternative for showing such amount json data in highcharts or any other charting api without degrading the performance occurring due to http response payload size?

And yes, The json data to be fetched can go upto **200 MB**.

Thanks

Comment: In case of such huge amount of data, using lazy loading seems the most reasonable solution. Take a look at this Highcharts demo https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/48-loading-millions-of-points-in-highcharts/.

Comment: I did thought of same but for that data needs to be saved to database but the data for each record is too big that if i try to insert data into mysql then for each record id there will be around 1 million rows. so we are currently saving data in file systems.